# IIS - Request filtering - 2 Domain Pointing to same physical path

Tags: iis-8.5, asp.net-mvc

Is it possible to have different request filtering rules for two domain pointing to same site(Physical folder)? Example - I've an Umbraco site and I want to point two domain to same physical folder/website. One domain will have access to admin section while other will not be allowed to access admin section.
www.xxxxx.com will only be allowed to access public content
www.admin.xxxxx.com will allow to access admin as well as public content.

Admin contents are available only if user has access to (say)folder named "ABC".

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can move the settings for `<system.webServer><security><requestFiltering>` from the web.config of your root directory into the global ApplicationHost.config file, using two `<location path="Site Name">` nodes you can specify different settings for different sites.

However this alone does not protect your admin section, what prevents a user from using the other URL?